# BAT file to delete entire folder with only a part specific of the folder

Tags: batch-file

Since, I'm nerd about these BAT files programming to finding over internet for the specific matter with no answer, I'm asking here. By going through various posts, now i know it is possible.

Ok so here it is what I want. First of all its windows 7 and the folder is placed in default Download directory meaning the path to the folder contains the username. And the folder name may be anything but must include the part "backup" either at beginning or end. I want this folder to be selected and remove the entire content including the subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /d %%F in (
  "%homepath%\Downloads\*backup"
  "%homepath%\Downloads\backup*"
) do rd /s /q "%%F"
```

Comment: @user1926208 - If a post fully answers your question, then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted per question. Once you reach 15 rep points, you will gain the privilege to up vote as many answers as you find useful, including answers to other people's questions. That action awards the answer poster 10 points.